# What does "flesh/sarx" mean in "And unless the Lord had shortened those days, no flesh would be saved..".Mark 13:20?

Tags: mark

**Mark 13:20**

> "And unless the Lord had shortened those days, no flesh would be saved; but for the elect's sake, whom He chose, He shortened the days". flesh/sarx. NKJV

Has "**flesh**" being saved a different connotation to, for example,  "**His people**" being saved,  as in
Matthew 1:21? Mat 1:21:

> "He will save His people from their sins".

**Mark 14:38**

> "Watch and pray, lest you enter into temptation. The spirit indeed is willing but the flesh is weak".

Is "flesh" in Mark 13:20 the same as "flesh" in Mark 14:38? i.e. not the whole of "human life" but an aspect of it.

If I understand Matthew Henry he links "flesh" with "The Jews". With regard to Mark 13:20 he says:

> "The Jews in rebelling against the Romans and in persecuting the Christians,  hastened their own ruin apace".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Sarx* always means flesh and never the spirit. It is that which is cursed and perishes. Thus it refers to the physical body from the cursed ground as opposed to the invisible spirit from God. This is always the meaning. It never means "his people", although it can mean "the flesh of his people" based on the context of whose flesh is being discussed. So yes, it is the same flesh. Here are some examples (KJV):

- Mark 10:8
  *And they twain shall be one flesh: so then they are no more twain, but one flesh.*

Note that there is no marriage in heaven. It is purely a union of the flesh and is dissolved on death.

- Matthew 26:41
  *Watch and pray, that ye enter not into temptation: the spirit indeed is willing, but the flesh is weak.*
- Matthew 16:17
  *And Jesus answered and said unto him, Blessed art thou, Simon Bar-jona: for flesh and blood hath not revealed it unto thee, but my Father which is in heaven.*

The physical body (in this case, the mind within the physical body) cannot see Messiah, only the Father can reveal him.

So in Matt 24.22, the meaning is that the physical bodies would be destroyed if those days [e.g. the period of tribulation] were not shortened. Thus it describes a series of events of increasing devastation that, if they were were allowed to continue, would lead to the destruction of everyone [within the universe being described -- e.g. Jerusalem or some other area depending on your interpretation] -- but for the sake of saints that are alive at this time, the tribulation is not allowed to continue but is "cut short".

Comment: Is your "The physical body cannot see Messiah, only the Father can reveal him" the same as "yet I will see God in my flesh" Job 19:26?

Comment: IMO, yes, Job is prophesying that after his physical flesh is destroyed (by worms), he will be clothed with a new body (that is not cursed), and in that new body, he will stand again and see God. But for those with the cursed body, seeing God's glory results in instant annihilation. See ἐπιφάνεια in 2 Thess 2.8 or Ex 33.20

Comment: Good answer. +1.